# Rails scope with 2 where clauses

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails scope statement where I want 2 where clauses.  (I will clean up the hardcoding when I've got it working).

This is in my workorder model:

```
  scope :laborok, where("wostatus_id NOT IN (?)", [231, 230, 8466, 8467, 232] ) and where("maxsynch = (?)", "N" )
```

The logic is if the workorder status (wostatus.id) is not one on the values and the workorder.maxsynch is equal to "N"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can chain the where() methods:

```
scope :laborok, where("wostatus_id NOT IN (?)", [1]).where("maxsynch = (?)", "N")
```

Whatch out, I replaced your array of IDs with `[1]`!
Here is the code with your array of IDs:

```
scope :laborok, where("wostatus_id NOT IN (?)", [231, 230, 8466, 8467, 232]).
                  where("maxsynch = (?)", "N")
```

Answer (score 2):

Why chaining?

```
class Workorder < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :laborok, lambda do |ids, maxsynch| 
        where("wostatus_id NOT IN (?) AND maxsynch = ?", ids, maxsynch)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

What is put into the string is simply passed along to your DB adapter, with the values of the parameters substituted in. So, the simplest form is to just use the `AND` keyword:

```
scope :laborok, where(["wostatus_id NOT IN (?) AND maxsynch = (?)", [231, 230, 8466, 8467, 232], "N"] )
```

With multiple `?` in the `where` string, the first parameter is the string passed to your DB adapter, while subsequent parameters are substituted into the string, in the order provided.

Chaining works okay as well if it's more readable in your specific case:

```
scope :laborok, where("wostatus_id NOT IN (?)", [231, 230, 8466, 8467, 232]).
                where("maxsynch = (?)", "N")
```

Many of the [ActiveRecord Query Interface methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) can be chained in this way.