# Rails scope lambda with 2 where clauses

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, lambda, scope

I have this which nicely gives me next and previous items:

```
scope :next, lambda {|id| where("id > ?",id).order("id ASC") } 
scope :previous, lambda {|id| where("id < ?",id).order("id DESC") }

def next
 Item.next(self.id).first
end

def previous
 Item.previous(self.id).first
end
```

In my view:

```
<%= link_to @item.previous, title: "xxx" do %>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" style="color:#eeeeee"></span>
<% end %>
```

I would like to enhance above so that I don't just get the next/previous item but the next/previous item which has the same :source_id (my item's have source_id).

Found two similar question here but can't apply it to my example:

[How to have multiple conditions in a named scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623668/how-to-have-multiple-conditions-in-a-named-scope)

[Rails scope with 2 where clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322555/rails-scope-with-2-where-clauses)

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add conditions to your scopes.

```
scope :next, lambda {|id, source_id| where("id > ? AND source_id> ?", id, source_id).order("id ASC") } 
def next
  Item.next(self.id, self.source_id).first
end
```

You have a lot of options if you want to keep around your old scope with just `id`--make a new scope with a different name, check if `source_id` is `nil` in your lambda block and give it a default value (or change the where clause).

I'd recommend not bothering with your scopes though, if you're only using them to define your next/previous methods. You could just cut to the chase with

```
def next
  Item.where("id > ?", self.id).first
end
```

Comment: thanks big time! Which one is better: with scope or without? Without is less code, more simple to me. Maybe it's faster too?

Comment: It's actually the exact same speed--if you look at the Rails guide on scopes, they're just syntatic sugar for class methods. I'd say without for form reasons, since it doesn't make sense to write a scope if you're never going to use the scope on its own.

Answer (score 0):

It's more universal to go for `created_at` comparison for the previous scope because `id` may be a random number (to hide the total number of purchases for example)